# GET method works, DELETE method throws 400

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, httprequest

I'm developing a ASP.NET Core website and calling methods from the controllers. I want to make a method to delete entities, and want to use `[HttpDelete]` for semantic purposes.

If I use `[HttpGet]` tag in the Controller method and try to access it via JQuery, it works:

**CompanyController:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route(nameof(DeleteSite))]
public ActionResult DeleteSite(int id)
{
    return Json("ok");
}
```

**JQuery request:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("DeleteSite","Company")?id=" + currentSiteIdToDelete,
    type: "GET",

    success: function (e) {
        console.log("yay")
    })
```

It starts throwing 400 Bad Request errors if I try to switch the method to *DELETE*, changing it in the controller and the call:

**CompanyController:**

```
[HttpDelete]
[Route(nameof(DeleteSite))]
public ActionResult DeleteSite(int id)
{
    return Json("ok");
}
```

**JQuery request:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("DeleteSite","Company")?id=" + currentSiteIdToDelete,
    type: "DELETE",

    success: function (e) {
        console.log("yay")
    })
```

Is there something else the *DELETE* method requires to work? I can't use route parameters as `currentSiteIdToDelete` is compiled in client-side and I intent to use `@Url.Action()` to reach the Controller.

Comment: Are you hosting this on IIS?  If so, which version are you using?  You sometimes have the explicitly add additional verbs to the IIS configuration for your website

Comment: @Martin I am using IIS Express to debug the application, and its version is 10.0.17763.615.1. Didn't think that could be the problem.